# Databinding WPF combobox doesn't work twoway

Tags: wpf, data-binding, c#-3.0, combobox

I have a combobox, which is filled with enums via data binding and this works quite well. Also the binding of the selected item to a property works fine.

I have set the binding to the property to TwoWay, but if the property MyDbType changes, the combobox changes not.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dbEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="utils:DbType" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox Margin="0" Name="comboDbType" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dbEnum}}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrDbSettings.MyDbType, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
      AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, 
    Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1">
</ComboBox>
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `MyDbType` needs to somehow tell the binding system that it has changed. For that, there is the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface which you need to implement on the CurrDbSettings object's class and rise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `MyDbType` property. Something like this:

```
public class DbSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ...
   public MyTypeEnum MyDbType
   {
       get { return _myDbType; }
       set 
       { 
           _myDbType = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("MyDbType");
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Makes sense :) Thanks! Here's also the Howto for the implementation of the interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614%28v=VS.90%29.aspx